# Changing non-hanging braces to hanging braces

Tags: vim

What is the regex to change

```
class ABC
{
}
```

to

```
class ABC {
}
```

I can use J command for one line,but how to do this for entire file.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few of the answers suggest using a substitution command. To me, it feels more appropriate to use a [`:global`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/repeat.html#%3aglobal) command in combination with the [`:join`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#%3ajoin) command. Start by creating a suitable search pattern:

```
/\n{
```

This works for the simple example given in the question, but it may need to be refined depending on the contents of the file that you are working on. Once you've got your search pattern, you can run the global command:

```
:g//j
```

If you leave the search field blank, Vim automatically uses the last search pattern (this is also true for the `:substitute` command). I prefer breaking the global command into two separate steps, but you could just as well do it in a one-er. Here is the long-hand form:

```
:g/\n{/join
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
:%s/\(class.*\)\_.{/\1\ {/g
```

(updated)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following search and replace:

```
:%s/\n{/ {/g
```

Comment: i tried it earlier.. Some how it doesn't work. Don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

How about recording a macro, i.e.

```
/class               # search for class
gg                   # goto beginning of file
qq                   # start recording of macro
J                    # join lines
n                    # move to next match
q                    # stop recording
```

execute using `@q`

Comment: i need to change function headers also. So i guess, this is not enough

Comment: @robert that was not in your problem description :-) It's always good to describe the whole problem just not a sub-task...

Answer (score 0):

For your example this worked for me on gVim:
`%s /class.*\zs\_[^{]*{/ {\r/`