# Quick VIM question

Tags: vim

I remember seeing the following functionality somewhere on the web, but I can't seem to find it. If I have the following code:

```
void function1()
{
}
```

and I'd like to move the first opening bracket beside function1()

```
void function1() {
}
```

I think there was an easy way to do this in VIM. Right now I am going to all the brackets, change to insert mode, press 'DEL,' exit out of the insert mode, and repeat :P. Can anyone advise? Thanks!

Comment: you could try a more suggestive title.

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438583/changing-non-hanging-braces-to-hanging-braces/6439773) of a question from only a few days ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `J` to concatenate lines. You can move to the opening brackets via `[[` keys.